# Freeform and Google Recaptcha

Tags: solspace-freeform

We are looking to integrate FreeForm with the new Google Recaptcha (https://www.google.com/recaptcha), but are unsure where to begin. I was wondering whether anyone had any experience of doing this and can kindly point us in the right direction.

Any help greatly appreciated

Jonathan

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this questions as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write an extension that uses [freeform_module_validate_begin](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_validate_begin) hook. Inside if your extension method you can look for `ee()->input->post('g-recaptcha-response')`, and if present, [validate it via the reCAPTCHA API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).

If it fails, you can add an error to the `$errors` array, e.g.:

```
$errors[] = 'Sorry, but you failed the test. Are you sure you're human?';
return $errors;
```

Otherwise, you can just return the `$errors` array is-is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready to use [plugin](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/recaptcha-v2)